# ASP.NET Loading Large number of images

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, optimization

I'm looking for some help with loading a large number of images to a ASP.NET web form.

I want to break up the response from the server, so that images are loaded asynchronously to the rest of the response and shave off some of the load time.

What is the best method of handling the images in general to maintain speed around a site. If a website is rich in large images, how is best to handle them.

Can I break up the requests the page makes into section?  split out images requests or JavaScript requests etc?

Comment: You can pre-load the image if it's static. Use multi-threading to avoid UI freeze would be something useful as well.

Comment: You can look into [image lazy loading](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+how+to+lazy+load+images) options - re: "request as needed" (by client/browser). Hth....